# incorrectly displayed letters during the XML parsing

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm Trying to parse website: http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance ();
Parserhandler handler = new Parserhandler ();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser ();
InputSource is = new InputSource (  "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp");
is.setEncoding ( "iso-8859-1");
parser.parse (is, handler);
```

In general, I try different variants encoding utf-8, Cp1251 etc.

but in return I get characters like:

**Þæíîàôðèêàíñêèõ ðýíäîâ**

or I get an error

> unknown encoding

help me please.

Comment: Added a new answer. I ran this code to make sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get correct characters as following.

```
public void theMethod() {
    try {
        String uri = "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp";

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = getByteArrayInputStreamOfUri(uri);
        parser.parse(bis, handler);
    } catch (...) {}
}

public ByteArrayInputStream getByteArrayInputStreamOfUri(String uri) {
    InputStream is = getInputStreamOfUrl(uri);
    if (is == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(is, "Windows-1451");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        sb.append(sc.nextLine());
    }

    try {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes("utf-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

private InputStream getInputStreamOfUrl(String uri) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
        return connection.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I'm a beginner. What is a  connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

Comment: It sets http heaer "Accept" to a http request. The heaer specifies what data types are acceptable.

Comment: and the second parameter is also to write this way?

Comment: Yes. It's a media type of xml. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type

Answer (score 0):

```
        URL url = new URL("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "windows-1251"));

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance ();
        Parserhandler handler = new Parserhandler ();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser ();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
        parser.parse (is, handler);
```

Comment: oh sorry it works. just had to write a Windows-1251 instead of windows-1251

Comment: Strange...  The lowercase w worked for me.  Anyhow, the trick was to decode the Cyrillic char set outside of the SAX parser, since apparently the SAX parser wasn't capable of understanding which char set you wanted.  I'd be grateful if you could accept the answer as correct.  Cheers